# How to print preceding siblings in xpath

Tags: python, selenium, if-statement

I'm trying to get the preceding siblings of an element using xpath.

There are 2 siblings that I'm looking for:

```
sibling_two = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'tag')]/preceding-sibling::a[2]")
sibling_one = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'tag')]/preceding-sibling::a[1]")
```

If `sibling_two` doesn't exist, I want to output `sibling_one`

This is my code, but it's only outputting `sibling_two` values

```
if sibling_two:
    for i in sibling_two:
        print(i.text)
else:
    for a in sibling_one:
         print(a.text)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this to output both `sibling_one` and `sibling_two` values?

Thank you for taking the time to read my question and help out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `if` `else`, use two `if`s:

```
if sibling_two:
    for i in sibling_two:
        print(i.text)
if sibling_one:
    for a in sibling_one:
         print(a.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used `find_elements` which will return a `list` in `Python`.

I'm not sure if you really want to use `find_elements` or `find_element`.

In case you want to use `find_elements`

```
try:
    if len(sibling_two) == 0:
        print("We want to output sibling_one")
        for i in sibling_one:
            print(i.text)
    else:
        print("Since sibling_two seems to have something in it, we would extract from the same.")
        for j in sibling_two:
            print(j.text)
except:
    print("Something went wrong")
    pass
```

**Updated :**

```
j = 0 
for a in range(len(sibling_one) or len(sibling_two)):
    print(sibling_one[j].text and sibling_two[j].text)
    j = j + 1
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to respond. I tried your solution but it still outputs `sibling_two` only

Comment: @shorttriptomars : see above, updated 1 code